# Is it safe to kill all background processes in Android from a service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, background-process

I am trying to do safe process killing for salvaging memory. Is it safe to kill all background processes in a an activity by calling either `ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses` or `IActivityManager.killAllBackgroundProcesses`? I know it is painful in case one of the killed processes needs to be restarted, but is it safe? Is it possible that something crucial to system performance or user/system data will be lost?

Comment: In a short, yes there is a chance of losing information.

Comment: No, other services of other Apps/System are running. This can render your data and device in an invalid state.

Comment: I recommend against it. Android was built from the beginning to keep this from being necessary

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to do safe process killing for salvaging memory

The OS will terminate processes as needed to free up system memory. You do not need to do so yourself. By the time your process runs, there is enough memory to run your process.

> Is it possible that something crucial to system performance or user/system data will be lost?

It is certainly possible that user data will be lost. For example, if they were in the middle of a form, switched to some other application for a moment, and you decide to kill all background processes, they may well lose what they entered.

Comment: Thanks, for answering. Basically, the OS solution for terminating processes as needed to free up memory is not good for me as I am not writing a single application but instead modifying framework components. The point at which I need to free memory is not the same as the one seen by the activity manager. Also, regarding data being lost, I did some experiments and it looks like usually apps that go to the background are not automatically killed by killAllBackgroundProcesses. I think this is governed by the `importance` property, i.e. if the process has `IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND`.

Comment: @smichak: The point at which I need to free memory is not the same as the one seen by the activity manager" -- then, as part of your modifications to Android, you should be adjusting the activity manager logic, rather than randomly killing all background processes.